# Php convert hash to password

Tags: php, security, hash

For security work should use secure `function` to save password like `hash` in `php`.

When convert password to `hash` it is not Reversible, therefore if a person forget password, how get password?

Gmail or other account how sent your password?

Comment: They don't. They're sent a link to set a new password.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Sneftel above, Gmail does NOT send you your password if you forgot it.  Any system that does has a serious security issue.

The correct way to handle this is via password reset, under the assumption that you have the user's email address, you can send them a time-limited link to allow them to reset the password.  (I.e. When the user clicks the link from their email, this counts as proof that they are the legitimate user requesting password reset). This technique is fairly common in the industry.  However if you are an email provider (I guess you are not), then you need alternate means to do password resets such as mobile phone verification.  For the love of God please don't do secret questions, they have known security issues yet some big players (Apple) continue to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ever have to reverse a hash, that is the point in storing them like that. Perhaps give the user an option to reset their password but avoid sending them out their current password. If it is essential this is done, then you will need to store them plaintext or using some algorithm you have made to encrypt them.